# ODBC can't connect libmyodbc3-3.51.27.so not found

Tags: linux, odbc, centos, unixodbc

I keep getting that error. However, I see the file there under the directory pointed by the error. I don't understand why it thinks it is not there.

I am running CentOS 64 bit and trying to install storegrid on it. I've looked at the other machines and the directory permissions are the same. It works on those machines.

Is there something else I am missing?

```
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc3-3.51.27.so' : file not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've see this kind of error before. That lib has another lib linked to it which cannot be found.

You can view all the libs which are required for this lib to work by doing this

ldd /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc3-3.51.27.so

In this case you'll want to run

ldd /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc3-3.51.27.so | grep -i odbc

This will show you that libmyodbc3-3.51.27.so requires libodbc.so.1

Now, libodbc.so.1 is part of unixODBC-2.3.0 but CentOS comes with unixODBC-2.2.14 which has libodbc.so.2

You'll need to create a symbolic link from libodbc.so.1 to libodbc.so.2 and that shod fix the problem.

Comment: Actually it turned out that mysql.sock file sym link under tmp was brokan. Anyway, it is fixed now. Thanks for your answer.